# Using Linq to compare a list with a set of lists in C#

Tags: c#, linq, list, comparison

I have a website containing news stories. Each story has a list of tags associated with it. Other pages on the site also have a list of tags.
On one of the other pages I want to list all the news stories that have one or more tags in common with the list of tags on the current page.
I have written some Linq code that compares a single tag to the tags on each of the news stories but I need to extend it so that it works with a list of tags.

```
query = query.Where(x => x.Tags.Contains(currentTag));
```

What I want to do is replace `currentTag` with a list of tags. The list can contain between 1 and 6 tags. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `Intersect` + `Any`:

```
query = query.Where(x => x.Tags.Intersect(tagList).Any());
```

This presumes that `Tags` actually is an `IEnumerable<string>`or another type that overrides `Equals` + `GetHashCode`. If that's not the case you can  provide a custom `IEqualityComparer<Tag>` for `Intersect`.

So  `tagList` is the `List<string>` of the curent-page as requested. But if you want to list all which have one or more tags in common with the list of tags *on all pages*, so an `IEnumerable<List<string>>`, you could use `SelectMany` to flatten them:

```
query = query.Where(x => x.Tags.Intersect(allTagLists.SelectMany(list => list)).Any());
```

---

If `Intersect` is not supported by your LINQ provider you can use following approach:

```
query = query.Where(x => x.Tags.Any(t => tagList.Contains(t)));
```

This is less efficient in LINQ-To-Objects since it's not using a set.

Comment: Thanks, but when the query executes I get: `The method 'Intersect' is not supported. Declaring type: System.Linq.Enumerable`

Comment: `x` is a set of pages from a Lucene index. `x.Tags` is  `IEnumerable<string>`

Comment: `query = query.Where(x => x.Tags.Contains("tag 1"));` works, but  `query = query.Where(x => x.Tags.Intersect(tagList).Any());` doesn't work

Comment: What LINQ provider is that, what is `query`? In LINQ to objects this works, maybe you are using a provider where `Intersect` is not supported (like `Linq-To-Entities`).